# .net LibreOffice Handle is not initialized exception

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0, libreoffice, openoffice.org

Our team updated an existing winform application to .net 6. Since this update we cannot open files with open office anymore. The SDK cannot be initialized anymore.

the following code throws an exception:

```
unoidl.com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext m_xContext = uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap();
```

exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Handle is not initialized.'

With the old version ( 4.8 everything works fine)
I already found two articles about it, but without any workaround/solution:
https://www.mail-archive.com/libreoffice-bugs@lists.freedesktop.org/msg864920.html
https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=148857